# How do I restrict a method call disabling it in webconfig?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

There is a method call in a a function, I want to restrict it call based on the value set in the webConfig file.If it is true,it should be called else not.

```
private IEnumerable<Contracts.Models.Translation> GetTranslationsIfEmpty(IEnumerable<Contracts.Models.Translation> translations, string locale, Expression<Func<Contracts.Models.Translation, Boolean>> where)
{

    if (!locale.Equals(EnglishLocale, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && !translations.Any())
    {
        var englishTranslations = _translationService.Get(where);
        translations = GetTranslations(englishTranslations.ToArray(), locale);
        AddNewTranslations(translations);
    }
    return translations;
}
```

I want to restrict the call of AddNewTranslation() in the function based on the appSetting in webConfig file

Comment: So, what the problem? Read web.config and compare value

Comment: How to read the value of that appsetting?

Comment: Have you tried to google it?

Comment: yes,i tried and i got solution also..but it's not working...

Comment: What is not working? Errors? Exceptions? SO does not write code for you, it can help to find problems in YOUR code. Now, you don't have code working with appSettings

Comment: I want to restrict to the value  in the webConfig file not an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define the appsetting like that;

```
<configuration>
   ....
   <appSettings>
      <add key="CallAddTransaction" value="true"/>
   </appSettings>
   ....
</configuration>
```

Then just compare the value;

```
bool callAddTransaction = false;//Set default value
bool.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CallAddTransaction"],out callAddTransaction);
if(callAddTransaction)
{
    AddNewTranslations(translations);
}
```